# Cannot serialize custom CredentialProvider apache beam

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Im having trouble compiling my apache beam pipeline to a dataflow template. Im using a custom aws credential provider class to load basic aws credentials from GCP secret manager and see the following exception when building the template:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected IOException (of type java.io.IOException): Failed to serialize and deserialize property 'awsCredentialsProvider' with value 'org.example.iot.beam.providers.GCPSecretManagerAWSCredentialsProvider@69f90a92'
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.fromUnexpectedIOE (JsonMappingException.java:336)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes (ObjectMapper.java:3852)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run (DataflowRunner.java:1082)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run (DataflowRunner.java:196)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:323)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run (Pipeline.java:309)
    at org.example.iot.beam.IOTSqsToPubSub.runPipeline (IOTSqsToPubSub.java:30)
    at org.example.iot.beam.IOTSqsToPubSub.main (IOTSqsToPubSub.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

The thing that confuses me is that the credential providers, like StaticAWSCredentialsProvider for example, don't specify any json (de)serializers. I would expect my implementation of the credprovider to just work, because its kind of similar:

```
package org.example.iot.beam.providers;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretManagerServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.secretmanager.v1.SecretVersionName;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GCPSecretManagerAWSCredentialsProvider implements AWSCredentialsProvider {

    private static final String LATEST_VERSION = "latest";
    private final String secretKeySecretName;
    private final String keyIdSecretName;
    private final String projectId;
    private final String version;
    private AWSCredentials credentials;

    public GCPSecretManagerAWSCredentialsProvider(String secretKeySecretName, String keyIdSecretName, String projectId) {
        this(secretKeySecretName, keyIdSecretName, projectId, LATEST_VERSION);
    }

    public GCPSecretManagerAWSCredentialsProvider(String secretKeySecretName, String keyIdSecretName, String projectId, String version) {
        this.secretKeySecretName = secretKeySecretName;
        this.keyIdSecretName = keyIdSecretName;
        this.projectId = projectId;
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
        if (this.credentials == null) {
            this.loadCredentialsFromSecretManager();
        }
        return this.credentials;
    }

    public void loadCredentialsFromSecretManager() {
        try (SecretManagerServiceClient client = SecretManagerServiceClient.create()) {
            SecretVersionName keyIdSecretVersionName = SecretVersionName.of(this.projectId, this.keyIdSecretName, this.version);
            String awsKeyId = client.accessSecretVersion(keyIdSecretVersionName).getPayload().getData().toStringUtf8();
            SecretVersionName secretKeySecretVersionName = SecretVersionName.of(this.projectId, this.secretKeySecretName, this.version);
            String awsSecretKey = client.accessSecretVersion(secretKeySecretVersionName).getPayload().getData().toStringUtf8();
            this.credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsKeyId, awsSecretKey);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Error while instantiating secret manager client, check if default authentication chain is available on the machine", e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh() {
    }

}
```

Should I implement a custom (de)serializer for my credential provider, or is there an easier way to get this working?

Answer (score 4):

The exception looks like you are intending to use the credentials provider via pipeline options with `SqsIO.read()`, right?

For this to work you need a Json de/serializer that is aware of your specific custom provider. There's a Jackson Module ([AwsModule.java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/amazon-web-services/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/aws/options/AwsModule.java#L95-L251)) that defines a polymorphic de/serializer for `AWSCredentialsProvider` such as `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` and some others. Unfortunately that one is not extensible and you can't simply provide your own de/serializer for `GCPSecretManagerAWSCredentialsProvider` to make things work.

`AwsModule` is automatically loaded using the Java `ServiceLoader` (SPI) and I'm not aware of a way to override / replace the de/serializer for `AWSCredentialsProvider` with a custom one matching your needs once the module is registered.

The only hack I can think of is to shadow the entire `AwsModule` (so using the same fully qualified class name) with a module that contains only your custom de/serializer. But it might be a bit of trial error to figure out if anything else in `AwsModule` is needed...

But I'm wondering, can't you just use the `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` and initialise credentials accordingly? Looking at your code above it doesn't look like you have to refresh credentials:

```java
static BasicAWSCredentials loadCredentialsFromSecretManager() {
   ...
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
  AwsOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(AwsOptions.class);
  options.setAwsCredentialsProvider(
    new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(loadCredentialsFromSecretManager())); 

  run(options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. I do wonder why the de/serializers are not just registered on the classes itself.. This makes it very difficult to understand whats happening. The only reason I did not implement the way above is because I think the credentials will end up in the template itself, whereas using a provider would load the credentials when the pipeline starts running. And hence only the workers need access to the credentials, not the builder of the template.

Comment: @abel The respective classes are part of the AWS SDK (v1 or v2) and out of control of Beam. Unfortunately it's not possible to directly annotate those.

Answer (score 0):

I may guess that it's caused by the fact that your `GCPSecretManagerAWSCredentialsProvider` implements `com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider` which is not `Serializable`. On the other hand, Beam AWS SDK classes, like `StaticAwsClientsProvider` and similar ones, implement an own `AwsClientsProvider` interface which is `Serializable`. So, you may want to try to do the similar thing for your own provider.

Comment: From what I can see is that the AWSStaticCredentialsProvider also implements the same interface as my custom provider: ```com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider```